# Mongoose. Postprocessing of awaiting data

Tags: node.js, express, mongoose, async-await, mongoose-populate

I'm frontender and I do my first API with RBAC based on Express + MongoDB. I need to postprocess Role permissions which I've got by await function. Example (this code works great):

```
export async function getRoleById(req, res) {
  try {
    const role = await Role.findById(req.params.id)
      .populate('permissions');
    return res.status(HTTPStatus.OK).json(role);
  } catch (err) {
    return res.status(HTTPStatus.BAD_REQUEST).json(err);
  }
}
```

Result:

```
{
    "id": "5c27d6bfc51081331411dcd8",
    "name": "writer2",
    "permissions": [
        {
            "id": "5c27c43e2eb0c279ccd945ef",
            "action": "create",
            "subject": "task"
        },
        {
            "id": "5c27c4532eb0c279ccd945f1",
            "action": "read",
            "subject": "task"
        }
    ]
}
```

But I need another format of permissions:

```
{
    "id": "5c27d6bfc51081331411dcd8",
    "name": "writer2",
    "permissions": [
        [ "create", "article" ],
        [ "list", "user" ]
    ]
}
```

So I tried do this:

```
export async function getRoleById(req, res) {
  try {
    const role = await Role.findById(req.params.id)
      .populate('permissions')
      .then((foundRole) => {
        foundRole.permissions = foundRole.permissions.map(item => [ item.action, item.subject]);
        return foundRole;
      });
    return res.status(HTTPStatus.OK).json(role);
  } catch (err) {
    return res.status(HTTPStatus.BAD_REQUEST).json(err);
  }
}
```

Replacing then by exec doesn't change the situation. After executing of this code I have response 200, but without any data. Blank page instead of object with Role data.

I read a lot of articles about Mongoose queries, and why using async/await with callbacks is incorrect. Replace async/await by Promises is not acceptable way in my situation. But what should I do to get result what I need?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Data postprocessing makes by standard method `.toJSON()` of Schema. So we can create our own method, for example `.toMyJSON()` or redefined standard method. I choose second way.

In file `role.model.js`, where I placed Role Schema:

```
import mongoose, { Schema } from 'mongoose';
import uniqueValidator from 'mongoose-unique-validator';

import User from '../users/user.model';

const RoleSchema = new Schema({
  /* here goes Schema */
});

/* Redefine standard method toJSON */
RoleSchema.methods = {
  toJSON() {
    return {
      id: this._id,
      name: this.name,
      permissions: this.permissions.map(item => [item.action, item.subject]),
    };
  },
};

RoleSchema.statics = {
    /* Here goes static methods of Schema */
};

export default mongoose.model('Role', RoleSchema);
```

And now we can use this method:

```
export async function getRoleById(req, res) {
  try {
    const role = await Role.findById(req.params.id).populate('permissions');
    return res.status(HTTPStatus.OK).json(role.toJSON()); // Here we use toJSON method.
  } catch (err) {
    return res.status(HTTPStatus.BAD_REQUEST).json(err);
  }
}
```